# How to perform class balancing on an imbalanced data set

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have an imbalanced data set with more positive reviews(90%) than negative(10%), which options below should I follow.

1. Use `class_weight='balanced'` in GridsearchCV(Training & CV) and Logistic algo(Train & Test)
2. Split data into train,CV & test sets and then do oversampling on minority class by taking the majority class(my case its +ve class). Thereby both classes balanced
3. Undersampling- not considered due to information loss.

Comment: Different methods will have different impact on the classification result depending on your data, my opinion is that you should try all of them and let the result drive your decision.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, for natural language data, there are not a lot of good options.
-One fast way is indeed to undersample the positive class and oversample the negative one in order to bring some more balance. 
- A more sophisticated way would be to use [GANs to create more negative examples](https://becominghuman.ai/generative-adversarial-networks-for-text-generation-part-1-2b886c8cab10).